# Clear TextView from within TextWatcher method

Tags: java, android, events, android-edittext

I have a "current password" EditText and an error TextView which displays an error message.  I want to clear the error message when the EditText contents change, usually when the user types in another letter or erases something.

The error TextView is not being cleared even though the system prints the messages.  The TextView is only being cleared when the EditText loses focus.

Why is this happening?  Are these methods being executed on a different thread?  How should I clear the TextView immediately after the user types in a character?

```
    mCurrentPasswordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.current_password_edit_text);
    mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_password_error_text_view);
    mCurrentPasswordEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            //mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText("");
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText("");
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            System.out.println("called multiple times.");
            mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: do that in onTextChanged() method

Comment: @VivekMishra the same thing happens.. I already tried it in all 3 methods, the TextView is only cleared after the EditText loses focus.

Comment: But I have.  `mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText("");` that is my line for clearing the TextView.

Comment: You can make that textview invisible when there is no error

Comment: What if I want to show another error? Your solutions are not really helpful. -_-;;

Comment: On what criteria do you show error message ?? And if you want it to be cleared in after text changed method.   I think problem is some where else but not in textwatcher

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my problem.

Comment: Then you should post that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very weird.  I think this is a bug!

Instead of replacing the TextView with an empty string "", I put an extra space " ", which cleared the text immediately!  *smh

```
mCurrentPasswordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.current_password_edit_text);
mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_password_error_text_view);
mCurrentPasswordEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText("");
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText("");
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        mCurrentPasswordErrorTextView.setText(" ");
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually this is not a solution, setting `" "` text means that you didn't clear the text. You have just set whitespace text. I run your code from question and it worked, so could you post what is the device/Android OS version when such bug happens?

Comment: The bug happens in 5.0.2 api 21. I'm running it on an Asus Zenfone 2 Laser.